# JST Connector Female to Male Jumper, is this how it works?

Tags: power, connector, pins

At home I have a small laptop fan with a 1.0mm pitch JST Female connector, and I was looking for a Male JST Connector to hook on to the Female one I have at home.

I found this item on amazon, and apparently you are suppose to attach the loose male head onto the female head of the wired connector, as shown in the picture. 
[image][image]

**So my question is**, once I put the loose male head in the picture into the wired female head to the left, I can then attach the **male wired connector we just created into my female JST laptop fan connector at home?**.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the product page on Amazon?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Micro-4-Pin-Connector-100mm-Female/dp/B01DUC1M2O/ref=pd_lpo_vtph_23_bs_t_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=77C9KF6JNEZB5SZZZX7R

Comment: How will fan be mounted and what are your wiring skills?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The JST SH connector family series is described as a "wire to board" family, and the the male pins connector you picture is is intended for surface mounting to a board.

It is not clear that a "free hanging" male pins connector housing exists in this family in the way that they do for some others - for example, free hanging contacts of both genders are relatively well known in the slightly larger 1.25mm Molex picoblade family, and get used a lot as battery connectors for tiny flying toys.  Beware that even if you find the parts for a free hanging micro connector, doing crimps at this tiny scale will be challenging with a universal crimper, while the designed tool could well cost between several hundred and over a thousand dollars.

You could attempt to solder extremely fine wires to the surface mount contact tails visible in your picture, cover them with tiny heatshrink, etc, but this is likely to be extremely challenging and fragile - you'll need a soldering microscope, and a fair amount of luck and skill to get it done without melting the contacts out of position in the housing.

Realistically, just cut off the connector and splice on something more suitable.  If you just want to test the fan you can poke a couple of wire wrap wires in there, but that's likely to come apart, so only do it with a power supply that can tolerate a short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the visible pins on the male connector in your second picture are intended to be soldered to a PC board.  Presumably you could plug the female connector on you fan into the other side of the male connector.

The cable assemblies would not be used with your fan.

Comment: So this would work if I plug in the loose male connector into the wired female connector, as shown in the picture, and then plug that combination we just formed into my female-laptop connector?

Comment: No, it will not.  There is nothing in your proposed purchase which will join wires to the existing connector on your fan.

Answer (score -1):

Fans usually come with 4 pin headers with DC controlled speed or PWM or a tach wire. (yellow)   YOu can buy 5V fans that run off a USB port and suitable wiring or 12V or even 19V from your charger.

### More important is why does it get hot.

Has the dust been vacuumed?

Are you running too many sluggish security apps and startups?  Run MSCONFIG and task manager or get wise with useless apps or get a free trojan adware cleaner like adwcleaner.exe and run that often from a reputable site.

Is the screen too bright? increases charger losses and power needed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked.  No one said anything about something getting hot, and there's no indication that the intent is to put the fan back into a laptop at all.  Indeed, if the question asked were the laptop repair one you are trying to answer, it would be closed as off topic.

Comment: True , the question is vague about laptop fan application, and I was using my crystal ball.